# Sharepoint SPDocumentLibrary - Location of SPWeb.Lists in Database

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to figure out an error that SharePoint 2013 is throwing. I have a line of code that is trying to cast a member of a Web.Lists, and the List being returned is blank. The code is attempting to find the document library given a document library name in order to upload a document to that library. The problem is that the Request.QueryString that is attempting to populate the document library name is returning null or empty objects.

What I am wondering is how to find out what that QueryString is attempting to point to. Specifically, the QueryString has the List id in the front of it, followed by what appears to be the correct path and name info for the library. Does anyone know where in the SharePoint database you can find where these List objects are referring to?

EDIT:

Here is some of the code that is breaking:

This is where we try and find the document library name by the request query string:

```
documentLibraryName = Request.QueryString[TableNameQueryString];
```

That value is getting filled with null, regardless of passing a value with the tablenamequerystring.

And here is where we attempt to assign the document library according to the name we were supposed to retrieve earlier:

```
documentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)base.Web.Lists[documentLibraryName];
```

Comment: Can you show what your code looks like?

Comment: Is the request coming from SharePoint or is it from some other app? Can you show an example of what the query string looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `dbo.AllLists` table in the SharePoint content database.

Comment: Caution ! Operating directly on sharepoint DB is not supported by Microsoft. Try to see on ULS log or use some tools like [Sharepoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com/) to see whats is wrong with the list.